# Fetch form data of webview in android application

Tags: android, facebook, caching, webview, form-data

I am creating a sample app for facebook in Android using the facebook SDK.

I am using the default login approach, where the user is shown a webview with the Facebook login page. The user enters the credentials here & is authenticated.

Now if the login is successful, i want the username & password entered on the login page of webview in my android app.

How to achieve this?

Comment: I got the same problem,,  we can at least use and locate the  cookies of native and webview at the same place and have to try after native code logins automatically refresh the webview ! Not sure about this Idea works or not!!!

Answer (score 1):

**Please don't do this!** I hope that this isn't available and grabbing this would be in violation of the Facebook terms of service. The whole point of oauth is so developers don't have access to your email address and password.

Comment: Not sure about this Idea works or not!!!  we can at least use and  locate the cookies of native and webview at the same place and have to try after native code logins automatically refresh the webview ! do you think it's right solution??   In simple words when actvity able to login fb by fb sdk when new  html fb page opens in webview it should automatically login whithout prompting login since it's already logged in native fb activity..  thanks